# Create Folder o Save in Temp

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 11 (Windows 8 Developer) i have create a downloader file:

```
string sUrlToReadFileFrom = "http://mysite/1.mp3";
int iLastIndex = sUrlToReadFileFrom.LastIndexOf('/');
string sDownloadFileName = sUrlToReadFileFrom.Substring(iLastIndex + 1, (sUrlToReadFileFrom.Length - iLastIndex - 1));
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://mysite/1.mp3"), "C:\\Windows\\Temp" + "\\" + sDownloadFileName);
```

But it doesn't work start! If I change the folder  "C:\Windows\Temp" in "E:\Temp" the download start. The drive C:\ doesn't work, why?
It is possible save in temp folder or you've other idea?

Comment: +1 for early adoption of W8 :)

Comment: thanks for all answer! And remember: Windows is the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this:

```
string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

does it work?

Answer (score 4):

Not having played with Widnows 8 yet, this is only conjecture, but it's likely you don't have write permissions to that location on the C:\ as a standard privilege user.

Answer (score 2):

Use the environment variable instead

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.LocalApplicationData)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the temp folder path:

```
string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

- [`Path.GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)
- [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) for example `LocalApplicationData` or `MyDocuments`